# Postgresql separate backups for different clusters

Tags: bash, postgresql, database-backups

I have this script for backing up postgresql databases

```
#!/bin/bash
# Location to place backups.
backup_dir="/path/to/backups/"
#String to append to the name of the backup files
backup_date=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
#Numbers of days you want to keep copie of your databases
number_of_days=7
databases=`psql -l -t | cut -d'|' -f1 | sed -e 's/ //g' -e '/^$/d'`
for i in $databases; do
  if [ "$i" != "template0" ] && [ "$i" != "template1" ]; then
    echo Dumping $i to $backup_dir$i\_$backup_date
    pg_dump -Fc $i > $backup_dir$i\_$backup_date
  fi
done
find $backup_dir -type f -prune -mtime +$number_of_days -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Only one cluster was used on server, so everything was fine. But now one new cluster was created. So I got thinking if backups will be done properly and if not how to make sure it will do backups properly for every cluster?

Will this script now goes over every cluster and do backups for all databases in all clusters? If so, there might be name clashes.

How could I make sure it would do backups in different directories for different clusters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating second script to backup another cluster databases. Well it is not very elegant, but it works. If anyone could write more universal script (and that one script could be used for all DB backups) so it would take in consideration different backup directories and clusters, please post it as answer (as it would be better solution)

Second script looks like this (ofcourse it would be best to merge both scripts into one):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Location to place backups.
        backup_dir="/path/to/backups2"
#String to append to the name of the backup files
        backup_date=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
#Numbers of days you want to keep copie of your databases
        number_of_days=1
        databases=` psql -p 5433 -l -t | cut -d'|' -f1 | sed -e 's/ //g' -e '/^$/d' `
        for i in $databases; do
                if [ "$i" != "template0" ] && [ "$i" != "template1" ]; then
                        echo Dumping $i to $backup_dir$i\_$backup_date\.gz
                        pg_dump -p 5433 -Fc $i |gzip -f > $backup_dir$i\_$backup_date\.gz
                fi
        done
find $backup_dir -type f -prune -mtime +$number_of_days -exec rm -f {} \;
```